# Ruby Operators difference

Tags: ruby

I want to know what the difference is between = and ||= operator in ruby. In the documentation, it says  = %= { /= -= += |= &= >>= <<= *= &&= ||= **= are assignment operators .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a ||= b` is short for `a = a || b`

In ruby `nil`, evaluates to false. So if a is `nil` or `false`, a will be assigned b's value

Comment: This is wrong. There is no simple expansion of `||=` like there is with `+=` and the others, and *if* you want to find a simple expansion that is at least somewhat close to the actual semantics, it would be `a || a = b`, not `a = a || b`.

Answer (score -1):

The variable before `||=` will receive the value after the operator if it is `!= nil`.

Comment: No, it will also perform the assignment if `a` is `false`.